# At what operating temperatures would the Trent 900 need to operate, to equate to the efficiency of current geared turbofans?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, efficiency, geared-turbofan

What is the minimum optimum operating temperature (in degrees Celsius) that would be required for the Trent 900 to operate at, for it to attain the level of fuel efficiency of current geared turbo fans?

Comment: "*What is the minimum optimum operating temperature that would be required for the Trent 900 to operate at, for it to attain the level of fuel efficiency of current geared turbo fans?*" Do you know which is the "fuel efficiency" of the Trent 900 and/or the current GTFs or are you just asking for a "better efficiency" just for the fun?

Comment: There will be different answers for different operating points. I doubt anyone here will give you a good answer without major research. If you really want to know, get a [good engine simulation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_engine_performance#Performance_software), model both engines and then tweak the parameters until you get the answer you want.